# How to get monthly and yearly records by passing parameters

Tags: php, mysql

How to apply condition to get monthly record if month is selected and if year is selected it should return yearly records..

I am unable to apply if else condition for this.. here is my code..

If year is selected then it will be `'2017'` or `'2016'` etc it will be an year..
If month is selected then it will be like `'03'` or `'02'`

So here is how im trying to do it

```
$year= $_GET['year'];
$month = $_GET['month '];

if(isset($year)){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM records YEAR(record_date) = {$year}';
}elseif(isset($month)){
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM records Month(record_date) = {$month}';
}
```

but everytime it does into first sql, condition is not working, Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You have a typo (extra space) here: $month = $_GET['month '];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_GET['year']` return as empty. You need to check like this

`if(isset($_GET['year']))`